# Poor network performance: high numbers of system calls per second

Tags: networking, solaris

I have a storage server running Solaris 11.3 on an SE326M1 (basically, an HP DL180 G6) which has an integrated Intel 85276-based NIC (as far as I can tell, anyway). I've got some highly variable performance on the card and I think I've narrowed down the problem. I've disabled automatic link-speed negotiation and, while running `iperf3`, I see that, as soon as a network connection comes in, `vmstat` reports that the system is getting around 880 000 system calls per second; speed was anywhere from 100Mbps to 300Mbps. This behaviour is seen when the computer is directly connected to another machine or via a switch; the `iperf3` client was another server; that server has no problem maxing out its network ports at GBe speeds.

The 880 000 system calls per second seems to me to be a very high number and a likely proximal symptom to the problem. I tried the same thing on a different box and saw numbers in the low tens of thousands of system calls per second.

Does anyone have any diagnostic suggestions/solutions? Or am I just unlucky and need to get a different network card? Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I've disabled automatic link-speed negotiation*  Bad idea.  [Autonegotiation is a required part of gigabit or higher-speed ethernet specifications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet#Autonegotiation): "Autonegotiation is mandatory for 1000BASE-T."  *Does anyone have any diagnostic suggestions/solutions?* Re-enable autonegotiation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks; did not know that. More precisely, I should have said "I tried disabling" while following a suggestion at https://www.unix.com/solaris/229191-solaris-11-1-slow-network-performance.html ; I had, in fact, re-enabled it. Sadly, still slow lorises.